# Не могу разобраться со временем

Tags: javascript, дата, время

Я не совсем понимаю чем конкретно GMT отличается от UTC. Оба они показывают одинаковое время.

[Источник:](https://kerchtt.ru/gmt-i-utc-kakaya-raznica-chto-dolzhen-znat-o-vremeni-kazhdyi-programmist/)

> UTC — обозначает время на нулевом меридиане.

[Здесь](https://24timezones.com/ru/difference/utc/gmt) тоже можно увидеть, что это одинаковое время.

Вот этот код даёт UTC время или время гринвичского меридиана:

```js
let d = new Date();
console.log(d.getUTCHours());
```

А вот этот код выдает мне местное или поясное время?

```js
let d = new Date();
console.log(d);
```

Comment: [Отличие GMT от UTC](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5+GMT+%D0%BE%D1%82+UTC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко, то:

- GMT - среднее время по Гринвичу, связана с суточным вращением Земли, потому является неравномерной
- UTC - основана на равномерной шкале атомного времени

разница между ними очень незначительна, для повседневной жизни. Потому обычно они взаимозаменяемы

Если не коротко, то вам стоит прочитать:

- [GMT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%83)
- [UTC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)
- [Разница между GMT и UTC](https://raznisa.ru/raznica-mezhdu-gmt-i-utc/)

На счёт второго вопроса, в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) говорится, что метод getHours() возвращает часы указанной даты по местному времени.